# Print a Conditioned COUNT query with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I need some help with PHP, i wanna print a value from a `COUNT(*)` query but it's conditioned, my code:

```
<?php 
    require ('../login/conexion.php');

    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
        header("location: ../login/");
    }
    //I wanna do this
    $consulta_OD = '';
    function query_()
        {
            global $conexion, $consulta_OD;
            $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as total from gok_registro WHERE estado=3';
            return $conexion->query($sql);
        }

    $consulta_OD = query_OD();
    $costo_OD = $consulta_OD->fetch_assoc();
    echo $costo_OD['total'];                                 
?>
```

By the way, the connection to a BD is good since my code works, without the lines after the "//i wanna do this" comment. The query also works in the console.

The last line is to print the query in another part of the document, any help?

Comment: didn't understand what you want?

Comment: It looks fine. What is the problem you're having?

Comment: You lost me at wanna

Comment: what do you mean by conditional count?

Comment: @avisheks I think he means `COUNT(*)` with a `WHERE` condition.

Comment: The condition makes no difference to how you process the result. Your code should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL request looks good. 
But:

- the function `query_` is never call
- the function `query_OD` not exist
- `global $consulta_OD;` is not used in the function `query_` so useless

If you rename `query_` by `query_OD` your code should work